# Manage version on each form submission in Java

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I have  a requirement in Java Spring Web Application that whenever a Form is updated with new values, instead of uodating the data in oracle, we have to create a new record with a version number. So, what is the best practice to keep track of version. ? I am using java spring boot web application and Oracle DB

Answer (score 0):

Jpa has :

```
@Version
@Column(name = "version")
private Integer version;
```

but don't forget in edit mode u should send back last version from gui